# Shrink item effect versus locked door, what happens?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, objects

Unlike a growth effect, there is no clause about stopping the size change if one cannot burst something which restrains the change, so there are differing opinions about if the hinges and lock or locks (or some psionic or magical effect) on a door would restrain the shrinking effect or not.

Thus, can a door which is locked or otherwise restrained in some fashion be shrunk to gain access?

Answer (score 8):

**Using *Shrink Item* on a locked door should work fine**

A door is a discrete item, no matter if it's closed or open. Doors – even barred ones -  are referred to as items/objects in the rules (for example, in the section on *Breaking and Entering* in the Player‘s Handbook (p 165)).

The description of the *Shrink Item* Spell doesn't say that the spell won't work if the target item is held or restrained by some other object, creature, force or magic (as long as the target isn't a magic item itself). So I see no reason to rule that a door can't be shrunk because it is locked or fixed in it's hinges.

The given example *"Even a burning fire and its fuel can be shrunk by this spell"*  rather suggests that a DM should feel encouraged to be generous about what can be a valid target for this spell and what can be achieved with it.

Answer (score 3):

The "target" descriptor on "Shrink Item" reads: *One touched object of up to 2 cu. ft./level*.

The description goes on to specify in the first line (emphasis added):

> You   are   able   to   shrink   one   nonmagical   item  **(if  it  is  within  the  size  limit)**  to  1/16  of  its  normal  size  in  each  dimension  (to  about   1/4,000   the   original   volume   and   mass).

As I read it, the spell doesn't allow shrinking a part of an object. Only whole objects or collections of objects that fit within the target volume.

Your DM will have to rule whether the door counts as part of the wall because of the hinges and locks.

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but if the door was part of the wall, it wouldn't be a door.